# French babel conflict with quantikz

Tags: babel, babel-french, quantikz

I've noticed a strange behavior using the `babel` and `quantikz` packages. The following code:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{quantikz}
        \lstick{\ket{0}} & \phase{\alpha} & \gate{H} & \phase{\beta} & \gate{H} & \phase{\gamma} & \rstick{Arbitrary\\pure state}\qw
    \end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

produces the following output:
[image]
while changing the `english` option to the `french` one in `babel` produces the following:
[image]
This happens when loading `babel` with `french`, `frenchb`, `french, english` or `english, french` options. Loading `babel` without any options works as expected. Any idea on how can I have `babel` in `french` while having the possibility to use `\lstick` and `\rstick`? And any idea on why does `quantikz` behave like this in the first place?

Comment: french conflicts with lots of stuff, try\usetikzlibrary{babel}.

Comment: I confirm this works here. In general, this is because `babel-french` makes the `:` active when running with pdfTeX (in order to provide proper spacing around this punctuation sign, as well as a few others like `;`, `!` and `?`); this causes problems because TikZ uses `:` a lot in its input syntax.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you mean generally?
That joke aside, this indeed works, thank you very much! Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it?